Check if timeslot is available (type free)

Hereby the HTML code, I would like to select a timeslot (at 21:00) which is free, in the code below. Only Padel Buiten 2 and Padel Buiten 3 are available. I prefer to book PAdel Buiten 3 at 21:00 hr. My question is how can I use python to determine if a timeslot is empty, or not. The right order should be, Padel Buiten 3, Padel Buiten 2, Padel Buiten 4, Padel Buiten 6, Padel Buiten 7. Is PAdel Buiten 3 free? Then he has to make aa booking, otherwise, PAdel Buiten 2 is it's free.
<tr utc="1732564800" data-time="21:00">
    <th class="matrix-timeslot empty"></th>
    <td class="slot normal r-2992 s-1280 taken" type="taken" finishes="1732568400" id="matrix-res-11317517" tooltip="Padel Buiten 1:::" rowspan="4"><div class="slot-period"> 21:00</div><div class="players"> <b>Gereserveerd</b></div></td>
    <td class="slot normal r-4435 s-1280 free peak" type="free" slot="4435" title="Padel Buiten 2" rowspan="4"><div class="slot-period"> 21:00</div></td>
    <td class="slot normal r-4436 s-1280 free peak" type="free" slot="4436" title="Padel Buiten 3" rowspan="4"><div class="slot-period"> 21:00</div></td>
    <td class="slot normal r-4437 s-1280 taken" type="taken" finishes="1732568400" id="matrix-res-11310116" tooltip="Padel Buiten 4:::" rowspan="4"><div class="slot-period"> 21:00</div><div class="players"> <b>Gereserveerd</b></div></td>
    <td class="slot normal r-4616 s-1280 blocked b-133207 by-blockcourt" type="blocked" slot="133207" tooltip="Padel lessen (11-11-2024 - 10-02-2025)<br>(17:00 - 22:00)"><div class="reason"> Padel lessen</div></td>
    <td class="slot normal r-4617 s-1280 taken" type="taken" finishes="1732568400" id="matrix-res-11310115" tooltip="Padel Buiten 6:::" rowspan="4"><div class="slot-period"> 21:00</div><div class="players"> <b>Gereserveerd</b></div></td>
    <td class="slot normal r-4618 s-1280 taken" type="taken" finishes="1732568400" id="matrix-res-11311773" tooltip="Padel Buiten 7:::" rowspan="4"><div class="slot-period"> 21:00</div><div class="players"> <b>Gereserveerd</b></div></td>
    <td class="slot normal r-4619 s-1280 blocked b-126740 by-blockcourt" type="blocked" slot="126740" tooltip="Reserveren via Playtomic (21-06-2024 - 31-12-2024)<br>(07:00 - 23:55)"><div class="reason"> Reserveren via Playtomic</div></td>
</tr>

New information:

As you can see (for test I'm using 18:00), but the courts 4 and 6 are available. But still I'm receiving the no courts available print.
Could you have a look at this code? I'm a python dummy :-) and verey thankfull for your help!!
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import sys

# Bepaal Webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  

# Open de website
driver.get("https://bent.baanreserveren.nl")  

# Tijd om scherm goed te stellen
time.sleep(1)

# START BOEKING 21:00 UUR
# Vul Gebruikersnaam in
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").send_keys("kbolk")

# Vul Wachtwoord in
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys("pw")

# Klik op Inloggen
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".form-submit3 > .button3").click()

# Juiste dag (3x klikken)
for _ in range(3):
    element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".matrix-date-nav:nth-child(3)")
    element.click()
    time.sleep(1) 

# Selecteer Padel Buiten uit Dropdown lijst
dropdown_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "matrix-sport")
dropdown_element.click()
element = dropdown_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[. = 'Padel Buiten']")
element.click()
dropdown_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "matrix-sport")
dropdown_element.click()
time.sleep(1)

court_preferences = ['3', '2', '4', '6', '7']
booked = False
for court in court_preferences:
    available = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[@type='free'][@title='Padel Buiten "+ court +"'][./div[text()='18:00']]")
if available:
    baan_boeking = court_preferences #here I would like to have the court number which is free
    print (baan_boeking)
    booked = True
    
if not booked:
    print("No available courts found") 
    sys.exit() #no courts availabe? No action needed, end of script

#Here I would like to add the next steps if booked if true.
print ("Execute next steps")


How does block 1 ever take longer than 3s? It's just a find and a click. I feel like we need more info. A link to the site and a description of the intended flow would help a lot here.

You also never explained what is "too long" for block 2.

What's the URL for the site? There's definitely a better way to do this. You should use a more specific locator to only select courts that aren't already booked. That will eliminate a lot of this code... but I can't write that code without being able to see the site.

It would be wonderful to have the code simplified. Is it possible to get in contact whit you? You can have a look via my screen. The site is (https://bent.baanreserveren.nl/) it would redirect you to (https://bent.baanreserveren.nl/reservations) after you logged in

Please post the HTML of the table shown in the first screenshot as text, properly formatted. I'll take a look and see what I can do.

I've added al little bit of the HTML code, at the start of the issue. maby it can help you

It will be easier if you could create a [mre] since we're unable to see the full HTML. As JeffC said, this could be improved a lot.

@WesleyBolk I've updated my answer.

I've completed the script to automate this process. I've commented out the final confirmation click because I'm assuming it will cost you money to create the reservation. This works for me consistently.
import datetime
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

#url = f'file:///C:/Users/jbcro/Desktop/sample.html'
url = 'https://bent.baanreserveren.nl'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# set script values here
reservation_length_in_minutes = 60
reservation_time = datetime.time(hour=21, minute=0) # hour=21, minute=0 is 21:00

def set_court_time(court_time_in_minutes: int):
    # court_time must be 30, 45, or 60
    if court_time_in_minutes != 30 and court_time_in_minutes != 45 and court_time_in_minutes != 60:
        raise ValueError("Court time must be 30, 45, or 60")
    end_time = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), reservation_time) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=court_time_in_minutes)
    select = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "end_time")))
    Select(select).select_by_visible_text(end_time.strftime("%H:%M"))

def set_player(player_number: int, name: str, member: bool):
    # player_number must be 2, 3, or 4
    if player_number != 2 and player_number != 3 and player_number != 4:
        raise ValueError("Player number must be 2, 3, or 4")
    e = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "players[" + str(player_number) + "]")
    member_select = Select(e)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[./td[contains(text(),'Speler " + str(player_number) + "')]]//input"))).send_keys(name)
    wait.until(lambda x: member_select.options[0].text != "--")
    if member:
        member_select.select_by_visible_text(name)
    else:
        member_select.select_by_value("-1")

# login
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").send_keys("kbolk")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys("Test@123")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Inloggen']").click()

# click Friday of this week
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tr[./td[@title='SELECTED']]/td[5]"))).click()

# select PADEL BUITEN
Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "matrix-sport")).select_by_visible_text("Padel Buiten")

time.sleep(2)
court_preferences = ['3', '2', '4', '6', '7']
booked = False
for court in court_preferences:
    available = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[@type='free'][@title='Padel Buiten " + court + "'][./div[text()=' " + reservation_time.strftime("%H:%M") + "']]")
    if available:
        # print("Book court: " + court) # for debugging
        available[0].click()
        # add steps to finish booking here

        set_court_time(reservation_length_in_minutes)
        set_player(2, "Player 2 name", False) # sample non-member as Player 2
        set_player(3, "Player 3 name", False) # sample non-member as Player 3
        set_player(4, "Player 4 name", False) # sample non-member as Player 4
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "__make_submit").click()
        # driver.find_element(By.ID, "__make_submit2").click() # this confirms the reservation. Don't click this until you're sure everything is correct.
        booked = True
        break # exit the for loop

if booked:
    print("Court <" + court + "> booked for " + reservation_length_in_minutes + " minutes.")
if not booked:
    print("No available courts found")


Soo, this code is awesome!!! Thank you. The only change what would be wonderfull is to select three days ahead. So If I run this code today he should look for a free space for Saturday, when I run this report tomorrow he should look for a free space Sunday

And last one, one of the players you have to search for Paul Meer, but his visible name is Paul van der Meer, at this moment he is giving an error

You can measure time your first block running using datetime module in Python:
import datetime

time1 = datetime.datetime.now()

# here you run your block 1 which execution time you need to check

time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
if time2 - time1 < datetime.timedelta(seconds=3):
    # run time.sleep
else:
    # execute block 2



Now that you have provided some HTML and more details, here's a much improved approach to finding and booking an open court.
Here are three examples of different court states from the HTML you provided: "free", "taken", and "blocked". There may be more but the one we want in this case is "free". I simplified the HTML below to make it easier to read.
<td class="slot normal free peak" type="free"    title="Padel Buiten 3">...</td>
<td class="slot normal taken"     type="taken"   tooltip="Padel Buiten 4:::">...</td>
<td class="slot normal blocked"   type="blocked" tooltip="Padel lessen...">...</td>

You can see from the above, we could use either the class name, class="slot normal free peak", or the type, type="free", to find free slots. For the free slots, the court name is in the title, title="Padel Buiten 3". With this info, we can create a locator that will find only free slots in the desired court(s).
You have a preferred court order so we can take that order as a list of string to provide the court number and add that to the locator and boom... we can find any open slot for the desired courts. We go through them in preferred order and as soon as an open slot is found, we reserve it and break out of the loop. Code is below.
court_preferences = ['3', '2', '4', '6', '7']
booked = False
for court in court_preferences:
    available = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[@type='free'][@title='Padel Buiten " + court + "'][./div[text()=' 21:00']]")
    if available:
        available[0].click()
        # add steps to finish booking here
        booked = True
        break # exit the for loop

if not booked:
    print("No available courts found")

NOTE: I don't know the rest of the flow to reserve a court so you'll have to fill that in yourself in the commented area, above. But, this should be enough to show you the approach and get you started.

Original answer:
I rewrote some of your code to simplify things.

I put the driver.find_element() and .click() on the same line since the variable was never used.

I put the code to switch windows into a function so it could be easily reused and shortens the overall code and makes it easier to read.

I added slow1 and slow2 to track if block 1 and block 2 exited longer than 3s. NOTE: I assumed block 2 slow should be 3s because the value wasn't supplied.

time.sleep() is generally a bad practice. You should be using WebDriverWait instead. I couldn't make the swaps because you didn't provide enough info.


Given all this, the updated code is below and should work but I obviously cannot test it.
def switch_to_new_window(original_window):
    for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
        if window_handle != original_window:
            driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
            break

# Bepaal het juiste scherm
original_window = driver.current_window_handle

start_time = time.perf_counter()

# Selecteer baan 3, tijdstip 21:00 uur
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr:nth-child(13) > .r-4436 > .slot-period").click()
baan_boeking = 3

# Ga naar het nieuwe pop-up scherm, waar gegevens ingevuld kunnen worden
switch_to_new_window(original_window)

slow1 = start_time - time.perf_counter() > 3
slow2 = False

if slow1:
    start_time = time.perf_counter()

    # Selecteer baan 2, tijdstip 21:00 uur
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr:nth-child(13) > .r-4435 > .slot-period").click()
    baan_boeking = 2

    # Ga naar het nieuwe pop-up scherm, waar gegevens ingevuld kunnen worden
    switch_to_new_window(original_window)

    slow2 = start_time - time.perf_counter() > 3 # is 3s slow?

if slow1 and slow2:
    # Selecteer baan 4, tijdstip 21:00 uur
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr:nth-child(13) > .r-4437 > .slot-period").click()
    baan_boeking = 4

    # Ga naar het nieuwe pop-up scherm, waar gegevens ingevuld kunnen worden
    switch_to_new_window(original_window)

# Scherm goed zetten
time.sleep(1)


I've added some more information, hopefully you can help me :-)

I did help you... I wrote the answer you are commenting under. Did it not work? It does what you asked.

Thank you, this will help, how do I make sure I select timeslot 21:00?

Is it possible to create a baan_boeking = number of the court which is booked?

I updated the locator to only look for 21:00. The value of court after exiting the for loop is the value of the court that is booked.

Thanks again! I've not added the code which I'm using, I still get into if not, but there are courts available. I've added it in the description

You can use my added code to reproduce it

OK. At this point I've answered at least 3 questions. The site rules are one question per post so we need to wrap up this question and if you have more questions, you'll need to create a new post.

Ok, thank you! I’ve created a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79225083/giving-return-the-court-number-if-it-s-free
